# Triggering a CSS transition from jQuery ajax.done()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I am trying to transition-in a new page using ajax and everything is working fine except that the CSS transition is not animating correctly. More specifically, I have an `<a>` element that when clicked fires an ajax `POST` request to my server. The server sends back an HTML file that is appended to the `body` of my document using jQuery's `.done()` deferred object method. However, when I add the CSS class to the new HTML that will make it transition into the browser viewport the style changes are applied instantly rather than being animated. If I execute `.addClass()` after a 1ms timeout the animation executes correctly. I assume the problem has something to do with the DOM not being fully finalized by the time my class is added, but I haven't been able to fix it without using `.setTimeout()`. While this is a simple-enough fix, it doesn't seem very robust, and it still means that there is something I don't understand about the process. Any tips are definitely appreciated.

Here are the relevant bits of code:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Intercepting Link Clicks</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="app.css">
    <script  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id = 'firstScene'>
    <a href="/server/" id = 'serverRequestLink'>Get Stuff From The Server</a>
</div>
```

app.js

```
$(document).ready(app);

function app () {    

$('#serverRequestLink').on('click', getServerStuff);
};

function getServerStuff (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'ajaxTest',
}).done(function(secondSceneHTML){
    $('body').append(secondSceneHTML);
    $('#secondScene').addClass('visible');
});
};
```

secondScene.html

```
<div id = 'secondScene'>
    <p>I'm the second scene.</p>
</div>
```

app.css

```
#secondScene {
background-color: blue;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
left:200px;
right: 0;
transition: all 1s;
}

#secondScene.visible {
top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
}
```

Comment: Does using `setTimeout` resolve issue?

Comment: @guest271314 It does resolve the issue if I use a delay of 10ms or more. 2ms works sometimes, and 1ms has worked twice. It seems like the effectiveness of this solution may depend on network conditions though, so I am hesitant to use it for a non-locally-hosted page.

Comment: Delay of `0` returns expected results here using `.queue()` and `.delay()`. Not certain if the issue is specificity of `#secondSource` `css` being applied. Will try a different approach as well

Comment: The network conditions should not matter, as `setTimeout` would be called within `.done()`, after request is complete

Comment: Can you include how you use `setTimeout` to return expected results at Question?

Comment: Can you try to check for the `offset().left` before adding your `visible` class to the element. Something like `if($('#secondScene').offset().left){$('#secondScene').addClass("visible")}` ? Without the use of `setTimeout`.

Comment: Use `setTimeout` , no duration is needed `setTimeout(function() {
      $("#secondScene").addClass("visible")
    })` .

Comment: @guest271314 Aha! That worked. Any idea why?

Comment: Best estimate here is that minimal, default 400ms duration of `setTimeout` allows `#secondScene` `css` to be set before applied `visible` `className` , where an actual transition is possible between the two style declarations.